# HTMLCanvasContext.drawImage() failing when passed an image found using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, drawimage

The idea of my code is create a hidden div which loads the image. When it's load event is fired draw it in the canvas. When I run the code I get this error 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE), yet I am waiting for the load event. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<div id="old-counties-image-wrapper" style="display: none;">
<img border="0" height="390" id="interreg-iiia-old-counties-map" src="/f/MISCELLANEOUS/old-map.jpg" /></div>
<p>
<canvas id="old-counties-image-canvas"></canvas></p>
```

and javascript

```
 $('#interreg-iiia-old-counties-map').load(function() {
    var canvas=document.getElementById('old-counties-image-canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
         var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
         var img=$('#interreg-iiia-old-counties-map');
         ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    //else {
    //    $('#old-counties-image-wrapper').show();
    //}
   });
```

The else part is commented out for now but is there for browsers that don't support canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$('#interreg-iiia-old-counties-map')` returns a jQuery object, while the `drawImage` method takes an `Image` object - the jQuery (`$`) function returns a jQuery object that wraps the original element to provide the usual jQuery functions you see.

You can get the underlying `Image` object by using the [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) method, but in this case it would be easier to just use `this`, which in the context of the callback function supplied to the `load` function, is the original `$('#interreg-iiia-old-counties-map')` DOM element. In other words,

```
ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
```

should work fine here. You also don't have to use a hidden `<img>` element - with `new Image` you can retrieve the image similar to what you're doing here:

```
var img = new Image(), 
    canvas = document.getElementById('old-counties-image-canvas');
img.src = '/f/MISCELLANEOUS/old-map.jpg';

img.onload = function(){
    if (canvas.getContext) {
         var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
         ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I know I could do it like that but the hidden div is there for the else part (i.e. for a browser that doesn't support canvas I can just show the hidden div and the image still displays.

Comment: @Belinda Ah, of course. You can still inject the image into the DOM with *this* method if no `canvas` support is detected, but I suppose your method would work better.

Answer (score 0):

And, now for my own take on a solution:

```
var imgId = $("#myDiv img").attr("id");
var imgObj = document.getElementById(imgId);
var canvasContext = $("#imgCanvas")[0].getContext('2d');
canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
```

It's ugly, but I don't think it's much uglier than the solutions presented above. There may be performance advantages to other solutions as well, though this one seems to avoid needing to load the image file from the server's file system, which should be worth something. I tested it in Chrome, Firefox, and IE10.